# What's up with Drogon's breath? Is it consistent?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S8E05, "The Bells", Dany uses Drogon to single-handedly burn

> the whole city of King's Landing.

This seem well within the capabilities of a dragon, except for

> the fact that the breath blows up walls and other stone constructs as if they were made of straw!

I cannot remember the breath of a dragon being described (books and show) or shown (show) to work like such before.

Since we have a fire-breathing dragon, I suppose realism has to take a back-step anyway. Is Drogon's breath consistent in universe?

Comment: In the books, Dragonfire is known to have melt stone and towers e.g. harrenhal's now mishappened towers which are a testimony to Balerion the Blackdread's wrath.  But other than that, no, it does not act like cannonade.

Comment: Drogon was one hell of a pissed dragon, that's why!

Comment: The dragonfire also ignited the remaining wildfire caches, causing further explosions.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Possibly. However there seems to be a lot more bricks flying than there are likely to be wildfire caches (if any such remain).

Comment: @MatthieuM. --- There definitely was wildfire - look for the green flashes following some of Drogon's attacks.

Comment: Anything the show (or books) show us is "well within the capabilities" of a dragon, by definition. Dragons are weapons of mass destruction in the world of GoT and ASoIaF. I think the portrayal of dragon fire is more than adequate!

Comment: <HandWavyPhysics>Hot things expand. Things heated very fast expand very fast. This is known as an explosion if it's fast enough.</HWP>

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Yes his breath appears to be consistent in universe.

In the *Histories & Lore* video for Harrenhal we see various images of when Aegon was burning Harrenhal with Balerion during his conquest. In some of these images you can see the breath blowing up the stone.

[image: Balerion burns Harrenhal]
<sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 2, Histories & Lore, "Harrenhal"</sub>

In Season 6 Episode 9 we see Rhaegal and Viserion break out of the crypts under the pyramid in Meereen to join Drogon and Dany flying to destroy the Masters' fleet and their breath destroys a wall.

[image: Viserion and Rhaegal break out through a wall]
<sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 6 Episode 9, "Battle of the Bastards"</sub>

And of course in that same episode and the latest one, Season 8 Episode 5, "The Bells", the breath pretty much wipes out the ships as if they are nothing too.

Also note Vicerion's blue fire in "The Long Night" has the same effect on Winterfell's walls as the "normal" dragon fire.

[image: Vicerion attacks Winterfell]
<sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 3, "The Long Night"</sub>

Comment: Howmuch did the fire blow up the stone, and howmuch did the fire weaken supports that led to a collapse? Given that Harrenhall is described as "towers that melted like candles", it seems very different in its destruction than the wreckingball-type rubble that's left of the Red Keep.

Comment: @JAD We don't get any information beyond the visual but the visual to me looks very much like it is destroying stone. And in either case in the Meereen scene the dragon fire is only blowing up stone.

Comment: then why wasn't viserion able to destroy the wall where Jon Snow was hiding behind? Could this be because the undead dragon was badly damaged?

Comment: @Termatinator Your guess is as good as mine, not directly aiming at the wall, he was damaged, plot armour, not at full strength etc.

Comment: Also, the Wall.

Comment: @EricDuminil Well the Wall is a special case considering it's ice so does melt a bit and has magic in it so I left it out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93636/discussion-on-answer-by-thelethalcarrot-whats-up-with-drogons-breath).